# функция для telegram-бота Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telebot

Цель такая: сделать функцию которая будет принимать 2 переменные (числа) и по формуле выдавать ответ.

Вот моя попытка но неудачная

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if (message.text == "Калькулятор логистики"):
        global log
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите цену логистики")
        log = bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, func2)
def func2(message2):
        global buy
        msg2 = bot.send_message(message2.chat.id, 'Процент выкупа')
        buy = bot.register_next_step_handler(msg2, func3)
def func3(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, int(buy) * int(log))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@tb.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == "Калькулятор логистики":
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите цену логистики")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Процент выкупа')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_3, message.text)


def start_3(message, value):
    proiz = int(message.text) * int(value)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, proiz)
```

Должен работать

Comment: cпасибо большое )